# Stop media player when html popup closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, embed, media-player

I have a simple page and a link on it which opens a simple popup ajax popup with embedded media player on it, like so

```
<object classid="..." id="mediaplayer1">
</object>
```

The problem is that after closing and disappearing popup it seems that Meda Player continues working, cause I am hearing movie sound. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by finding popup frame and setting `contentWindow.location = ''`

Answer (score 1):

Here is code to add it media player to your page: [Webreference](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jf/column5/index.html)

Here is code to pause/play it: [WebDeveloper](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=88436)

```
function handlePlayOrPauseClick(){
     var state;
      playerStatus = document.mediaPlayer.playState;
      if (playerStatus == 6) {
        document.mediaPlayer.play();
        document.playerCtrl.playOrPause.value = " Pause ";
      } 
      else if (playerStatus == 1) {
        document.mediaPlayer.play();
        document.playerCtrl.playOrPause.value = " Pause ";
      } 
      else if (playerStatus == 2) {
        document.mediaPlayer.pause();
        document.playerCtrl.playOrPause.value = " Play  ";
      }
}
```

You can use code for play/pause on window **unload** event to stop player.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheVillageIdiot, I will try it now, but why is it continue to play? Is it normal behavior?

Comment: to tell the truth can't say :(

Answer (score 1):

On the click of the close button of the popup with the media player in it, try removing the element. I'll use some jQuery for terseness:

```
$('#close_popup').click(function(e){ $('#mediaplayer1').remove(); });
```